# Porque valor fica diferente com printf e echo

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um calculo entre datas e horas mas ao exibir o valor com `printf` o resultado é um e com `echo` é diferente.
Com esse cálculo o valor é exibido corretamente:

```
 $Entrada = strtotime( '2010-05-26 08:00' );
    $Saida   = strtotime( '2010-05-26 11:15' );
    $Diferenca = $Saida - $Entrada;

    $hora = $Diferenca/3600;
    $min  = $Diferenca/60%60;

    printf( '%d:%d', $hora, $min );
```

O resultado é: 3:15

E dessa forma o resultado é acrescentado um valor no final:

```
    $Entrada = strtotime( '2010-05-26 08:00' );
    $Saida   = strtotime( '2010-05-26 11:15' );
    $Diferenca = $Saida - $Entrada;

    $hora = $Diferenca/3600;
    $min  = $Diferenca/60%60;

    $Resultado = printf( '%d:%d', $hora, $min );
    echo $Resultado;
```

O resultado é: 3:154

Vejam no [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bcb905c4ec85d0ec2769c9bd3190759203b93b3)

Comment: Para guardar o valor em uma variável, vc precisa utilizar o sprintf. O printf serve somente para  a exibição formatada.

Comment: Olá @lvr7, para você ver, não sabia disso, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `printf` é uma função que imprime uma string formatada no console e retorna o comprimento da string em números.

Por exemplo:

```php
// Irá mostrar a string "Luiz Felipe" antes dos três hífens.
$printedLength = printf("%s %s", "Luiz", "Felipe");

echo "\n" . "---" . "\n";

// Irá imprimir 11:
echo $printedLength;
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/onseBX)</sup>

Se você quiser atribuir o valor de uma string formatada, você deve usar a função `sprintf`, que não imprime ao *stdout* automaticamente:

```php
// Irá atribuir a string "Luiz Felipe" à variável `$formated`:
$formated = sprintf("%s %s", "Luiz", "Felipe");

// Irá imprimir "Luiz Felipe" ao console:
echo $formated;
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/ns0kkK)</sup>

---

Desse modo, quando você faz:

```php
$resultado = printf('%d:%d', $hora, $min);
echo $resultado;
```

Você está imprimindo o horário ao *stdout* e em seguida imprimindo o comprimento da string formatada (que já foi impressa no console).

No caso acima, você provavelmente quer substituir a função `printf` por `sprintf`:

```php
$resultado = sprintf('%d:%d', $hora, $min);
echo $resultado;
```

### Referência:

- [`printf`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php);
- [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Obrigado @LuizFelipe a dica foi espetacular e ajudou demais a entender o assunto, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebi, quando você utiliza %d você está pedindo para que o printf mostre o inteiro absoluto, daí quando coloca tudo junto no "%d:%d", sobram 0.25 minutos da hora, esta sobra é colocada nos minutos, de forma que, 15 + 0.25 ((60/4) minutos que representa a sobra) geram os 03:154 provavelmente por arredondamento.

Utilize a função gmdate para formatar do jeito diferente se desejar.

```
<?php
// Inteiros com timestamp inicial.
$Entrada = strtotime('2010-05-01 08:00');
// Inteiros com timestamp finaç.
$Saida = strtotime('2010-05-01 11:15');
// diferença.
$Diferenca = $Saida - $Entrada;
// Conversão de tempos.
$hora = $Diferenca / 3600;
$min = $hora / 60 % 60;
// formatar como GMT:UTC Date/Time.
$Resultado = gmdate('H:i', $Diferenca);
// Mostrar resultado
echo $Resultado; // A saída será 03:15
?>
```

Comment: Não creio que isso responda à pergunta. O autor deseja saber o porquê da diferença, e não como formatar a data em si...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Felipe.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação @LuisAlbertoBatista, ficou show.